# celery task registry for asynchronous tasks

Tags: python, asynchronous, rabbitmq, celery, ipc

I can't figure out how to define celery tasks in a modular way (i.e. *not* all tasks in the same file) and register them correctly for asynchronous use. I've tried all options I can think off:

- using the decorator based tasks
- using class based tasks
- using autodiscover_tasks on celery app object
- registering tasks manually, i.e. `app.tasks.register(Task1())` for a class based task
- executing celery worker in same directory as celery_app.py
- executing celery worker in the directory above the one containing celery_app.py
- specifying the app for the `celery worker` command with the -A option.
- *not* specifying the app for the celery worker
- specifying an empty "name" property in the class based task.
- specifying a name property containing with the correct module

Whatever I do, I always end up with 'KeyError' thrown by the task registry, but *only* when executing with `apply_async`. The synchronous version always works fine.

If anyone could give me a hint on what I should do to fix this, please share.

Here is a minimal example:

- minimal

  - task1

    - `__init__.py`
    - `task.py`
  - task2

    - `__init__.py`
    - task.py
  - `__init__.py`
  - `celery_app.py`
  - `start.sh`
  - `test.py`

**minimal.task1.task**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from celery import Task
from minimal2.celery_app import app
class Task1(Task):
   name = ""
   def run(self, number):
       return number / 2.0

app.tasks.register(Task1())
```

**minimal.task2.task**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from celery import Task
from minimal2.celery_app import app

class Task2(Task):
    name = "minimal2.task2.task.Task2"
    def run(self, number):
        return number * number

app.tasks.register(Task2())
```

**minimal2.celery_app**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('minimal', backend='amqp', broker='amqp://')
app.autodiscover_tasks(['task1', 'task2'], 'task')
```

**minimal2/start.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

start_celery_service() {
    name=$1
    pid_file_path="$(pwd)/${name}.pid"
    if [ -e "${pid_file_path}" ] ; then
        kill $(cat ${pid_file_path}) && :
        sleep 3.0
        rm -f "${pid_file_path}"  # just in case the file was stale
    fi
    celery -A minimal2.celery_app.app worker -l DEBUG --pidfile=${pid_file_path} --logfile="$(pwd)/${name}.log" &
    sleep 3.0
}

prev_dir=$(pwd)
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
cd ../
rabbitmq-server &
start_celery_service "worker1"
cd $prev_dir
```

**testing**

```
from minimal2.task1.task import Task1
print Task1().apply(args=[], kwargs={'number':2}).get()
> 1.0
print Task1().apply_async(args=[], kwargs={'number':2}).get() # (first time: never comes back -> hitting ctrl-c)
print Task1().apply_async(args=[], kwargs={'number':2}).get() # second time
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 194, in get
     on_message=on_message,
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 470, in wait_for_pending
     return result.maybe_throw(propagate=propagate, callback=callback)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 299, in maybe_throw
     self.throw(value, self._to_remote_traceback(tb))
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 292, in throw
     self.on_ready.throw(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vine/promises.py", line 217, in throw
     reraise(type(exc), exc, tb)
   File "<string>", line 1, in reraise
 celery.backends.base.NotRegistered: ''

#.. same spiel with Task2:
#..
> celery.backends.base.NotRegistered: 'minimal2.task2.task.Task2'

#.. same if I do name = __name__ in Task2:
#..
> celery.backends.base.NotRegistered: 'minimal2.task2.task'

# autodiscover had no effect
```

I've had the same behavior in Ubuntu inside a docker container as well as macOS, both on the latest celery version on Pypy:

```
celery report

software -> celery:4.1.0 (latentcall) kombu:4.1.0 py:2.7.13
            billiard:3.5.0.3 py-amqp:2.2.2
platform -> system:Darwin arch:64bit imp:CPython
loader   -> celery.loaders.default.Loader
settings -> transport:amqp results:disabled
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you can use `include` argument where you're creating your celery app. It'll register all tasks found in the modules mentioned in the `include` argument. For example:

```
celery = Celery(app.import_name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'],
                    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'],
                    include=['minimal.task1', 'minimal.task2'])
```

Edit by question poster: In addition, in order to get the correct import naming, the task class' name property needs to be set as follows:

```
class Task1(Task):
   name = __name__
```

Essentially, the value of `name` at task registering time needs to match exactly the name with which the task is imported at client side.

Comment: Thanks. Doing `app = Celery('minimal', backend='amqp', broker='amqp://', include=['task1/task.py', 'task2/task.py'])` produces `ImportError: Import by filename is not supported` when starting the worker. Are you using this in the latest celery version?

Comment: hold on. this gets me one step closer: `app = Celery('minimal', backend='amqp', broker='amqp://', include=['minimal2.task1.task', 'minimal2.task2.task'])`. This solves the registry error I had! The bad news is... even the posted minimal tasks just stay in status PENDING :(

Comment: Import the task modules instead of files or even each task explicitly. Like ‘minimal.task1’. This will resolve the import error

Comment: Good news! the PENDING issue was due to some zombie workers I had spinning around. After rebooting this is now fixed. If you update your answer with the include option from my comment I'll accept it. Also worth mentioning: The `name` property of the task class needs to be set to `__name__`. Thank you for your help! At least the additional grey hairs have lead to some results....

Comment: Answer updated with respect to modules. Registering each task explicitly or the entire module both are correct.

Comment: I've added some additional information to your answer, hope you don't mind. IMO it's rather hard to find complete information on celery usecases, so I want it documented as good as possible.

Comment: sure, no worries as long as it helps others :)